# Set null value to the array of enums C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a enum class "Figure" and board:

```
public enum Figure { X, O }

private Figure[,] board = new Figure[boardSize, boardSize];
```

When there are no values on the board, I want add null value to board.
Example:
`board[0,0] = null` - but it's wrong.
How i can do that?

Comment: Please read [ask]. "it's wrong" is not a proper problem description. If you research the actual compiler error, _"Cannot convert null to enum because it is a value type"_, you'll find plenty of results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enums are value types, so `null` is not a valid value for them.

Here's two solutions to this problem:

1. add a new enum value:

   ```
   public enum Figure { Empty, X, O }
   ```

You can now use `Figure.Empty` instead of `null`.

2. Use a nullable type:

   ```
   private Figure?[,] board = new Figure[boardSize, boardSize];
   ```

The little `?` after `Figure` allows you to use `null`.